# Modifying `org-end-of-line` within markup tags

Tags: org-mode

If I'm typing along in org mode, like so:

```
This is a sentence|. It is followed by another sentence on the same line.
```

And point is indicated by the `|`, and I hit `C-e`, I get a perfectly normal result -- I jump to the end of the sentence.

But! Now imagine I'm using org markup tags with a tool like `smartparens` that inserts pairs. I'm here:

```
I'm going to type a *bold|*
```

Press `C-e`; I want to wind up on the other side of the second asterisk. Instead, I wind up here:

```
I'm going to type a *bold*
|
```

All the way on the next line. Now I have to move point a line up and `C-e` again, which jumps me to where I want to be.

Is anyone familiar enough with `org-end-of-line` to know if this is intended? My current approach is to try and concoct an advice for `org-end-of-line` to make it go to end of line properly, but I'm not sure it's the right solution. Suggestions?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, but is having `smartparens` work for org-markup-tags the intentional behaviour you want?

Comment: @dangom yes, I would like closing tags inserted. Hadn't considered it might be a `smartparens` issue tho -- will investigate.